# How we get text value of an element

Tags: java, selenium

How we get text value of an element for the below code.

Code:

```
<div class="ui-datepicker-title">
    <span class="ui-datepicker-month">February</span>
    <span class="ui-datepicker-year">2016</span>
</div>
```

i need text value like "February 2016"

I tried these two examples

```
String title =  driver.findElement(By.className("ui-datepicker-title")).getAttribute("value");
System.out.println(title);

String title =  driver.findElement(By.className("ui-datepicker-title")).getText();

System.out.println(title);
```

But not able to get text value of this element

```
driver.findElement(By.className("ui-datepicker-title"));
```

Comment: You need to elaborate about *But not working*?

Comment: Is that element within a frame?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is because the id `ui-datepicker-title` does not have a value, it contains 2 children html elements.

You need to do the following to get the values:

```
String month =  driver.findElement(By.className("ui-datepicker-month")).getText();
String year =  driver.findElement(By.className("ui-datepicker-year")).getText();

String result = month + " " + year;

System.out.println(result); // February 2016
```

*note, i'm not a Java guy.

Answer (score 0):

Try with class name of span tag, as text exists inside span and not parent div tag

```
String month =  driver.findElement(By.className("ui-datepicker-month")).getText();
String year =  driver.findElement(By.className("ui-datepicker-year")).getText();
```

or if duplicates exists in page try using path

```
String month=  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='ui-ui-datepicker-title']//span[@class='ui-datepicker-month'])).getText();
String year =  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='ui-ui-datepicker-title']//span[@class='ui-datepicker-year'])).getText();
```